# Remove the following row if a condition is met

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset, rows

I would like to remove all rows that are followed by the same entry in R. I have the following colomn in a data frame:

```
"FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "FAILURE" "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"    "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "FAILURE" "FAILURE" "HIT"
```

I would like to delete all rows in which the "FAILURE" entry is followed by another "FAILURE" entry. So I would like to get the following colomn of the data frame back:

```
"FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE"  "HIT" "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT" "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"    "FAILURE" "HIT" "FAILURE" "HIT"
```

How can I check if the next row meets that condition and remove those rows?

Comment: What if a "HIT" entry is followed by another "HIT"?

Comment: Is the dataframe's column a vector of characters or  a vector of vector of characters ?

Comment: Hi, HIT is never followed by another HIT, only FAILURE can be followed by another FAILURE. And the dataframe column is a vector of characters

Answer (score 1):

All which had a hit with `FAILURE` and their `diff` is `0` are removed with:

```
. <- x == "FAILURE"
(. <- x[!(. & diff(c(FALSE, .)) == 0)])
# [1] "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE"
# [8] "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"    
#[15] "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE"
#[22] "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"     "FAILURE" "HIT"    

identical(., y)
#[1] TRUE
```

Data:

```
x <- c("FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "FAILURE", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "FAILURE", "FAILURE", "HIT")

y <- c("FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE", "HIT")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

Supposing I am having an entire dataframe like this: 

z <- data.frame(Variable1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),Variable2=c("FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE","FAILURE","FAILURE", "HIT", "FAILURE","FAILURE", "HIT","FAILURE" ))

How could I apply your method to an entire dataframe?

Comment: `. <- z$Variable2 == "FAILURE"` and `z[!(. & diff(c(FALSE, .)) == 0),]`